# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm using story board, i have custom tableviewcell class. I dragged outlets from story board to tableviewcell. In that i'm adding corner and colours for components like this. But i'm getting this error **Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. How to solve this

My code in tableviewcell class is.

```
import UIKit

class detailsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var chargesTableViewCellView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var typeLbl: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    chargesTableViewCellView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.10, green: 0.39, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.0).cgColor // Here I'm getting error
    chargesTableViewCellView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    chargesTableViewCellView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
}
```

Comment: do you connect chargesTableViewCellView with it's outlet at storybook or xib file?

Comment: have you assign this class to more then one cells on storyboard?

Comment: Yes I connected properly, I rechecked  @Moayad Al kouz

Comment: Yes, I'm using same class to my entire project for all tableview cells,  @Jogendar Choudhary

Comment: @iOS Could you try setting the `borderWidth` before `borderColor`

Comment: In objective c I'm using same tableviewcell class file @Jogendar Choudhary, but I'm getting only in wift

Comment: No, first I'm set colour, then width @ Carpsen90

Comment: @iOS did you try it?

Comment: @Carpsen90 , yes I'm getting the same error

Comment: Did you check if `chargesTableViewCellView.layer` is nil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179532/discussion-between-ios-and-carpsen90).

Comment: @ Carpsen90, could please explain about <layer>. How to check it

Comment: print(chargesTableViewCellView) I'm printing this view, but getting <none> in tableviewcell class

Comment: @iOS: You need to add check for re-use identifier, i am adding my answer, wait

Comment: @iOS I have added my answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have used more then one cell with single custom class so you need to add check with re-use identifier :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
   // "identifier" is a cell identifier so please change this identifier with your cell identifier witch is used this outlet
        if self.reuseIdentifier == "identifier" {
    chargesTableViewCellView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.10, green: 0.39, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.0).cgColor // Here I'm getting error
        }

    chargesTableViewCellView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.10, green: 0.39, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.0).cgColor // Here I'm getting error
    chargesTableViewCellView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    chargesTableViewCellView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
}
```

You need to add the check for `reuseIdentifier` that cell contains this outlet. this will work for you.

Comment: Yes, i'm using single class for many cells and those all are from different classes. If i write my code in cellForRowAt indexPath: it's working fine. But cellForRowAt indexPath: will call multiple times. That's why i wrote this code in custom class.

Comment: @iOS Yes, this will work when you right it in cellForRowAt indexPath but you need to add check in  awakeFromNib with reuseIdentifier.

Comment: @iOS let me know if you still face this issue after adding reuseIdentifier check

Comment: @iOS: You need to add check for all outlets

Comment: @iOS: you are getting this crash, because outlet getting nil, so please check with reuseidentifier for every outlet

Comment: Yes, I checked all outlets. I removed, deleted derived data and recreated all outlets

Comment: Ok, I will try one more time

Comment: your answer is working, I created sample project and applied your code. It's working, fine thank you. Now i will apply this code to my project. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it's working in my project also. Once again thank you very much

Comment: @iOS: Its my pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for your custom view like this

```
import UIKit

class CornerView: UIView {

func setup() {

    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.10, green: 0.39, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}
```

}

then you can inherit from your custom class

```
@IBOutlet weak var chargesTableViewCellView: CornerView!
```

notice: make sure for cell identifier from storyboard is the same in ViewController

Comment: how to assign colour to this chargesTableViewCellView

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Interface Builder and delete ALL of your references to the file. Select the storyboard container and click on the most right button in the Interface Builder. You will find a list of references in there. Click on (x) for each of them.

Reconnect after that.

If you changed a name, copied-pasted or moved around things in the storyboard, sometimes the references get mixed. It all looks good on Xcode, but the `id`s of the references have mismatches.